# Выполнение метода через промежуток времени rx java

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Есть задача отправлять данные по Bluetooth при помощи библиотеки RxAndroidBle.
Я написал метод который отправляет данные. Выглядит он сейчас вот так:

```
private void sendMessage(UUID uuid, String message) {
    if (connectionObservable != null) {
        connectionObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(uuid, message.getBytes()))
                .subscribe(
                        bytes -> {
                            //Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sendMessage: Данные успешно отравлены  ");
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sendMessage: Возникла ошибка при отправке данных " + throwable.getMessage());
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

Теперь сама суть. В методе `flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(uuid, message.getBytes()))`, необходимо вызывать метод по заданному промежутку времени. К сожалению не могу найти информации на этот счет, так как с RxJava пока только разбираюсь. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить пожалуйста что значит "вызвать по заданному промежутку времени"? Т.е. вам нужно вызывать через определнный промежуток времени что? всю Rx конструкицю или один метод и если один метод то какой уточните пожалуйста чтобы я правильно ответил?

Comment: Данил Сычев, Нужно вызвать только один метод writeCharacteristic()

Comment: сильно сомневаюсь, что в Rx есть шедулер для подписки, если об этом речь

Comment: В Rx есть оператор delay, используется для задержки на определенный промежуток времени. Пример:  .delay(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) ,  .delay(Задержка, Единицы времени) , встраивается так же как и .observeOn() или .subscribeOn()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connectionObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .delay(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // след  элемент обработается через 700 миллисекнуд
                .flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(uuid, message.getBytes()))
                .subscribe(
                        bytes -> {
                            writeCharacteristic();
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sendMessage: Возникла ошибка при отправке данных " + throwable.getMessage());
                        }
                );
```

Примерно так, промежуток между каждым обработанным элементом будет 700 миллисекунд